# Double numerical integral, in two steps

Tags: numerical-integration, numerical-value

Let me define the following function:

```
f[x_] = x
```

I have to solve the numerical integral:

```
NIntegrate[NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, y}], {y, 0, 1}] (*1*)
```

and obviously this gives me an error.

I know there is a correct way to do it and the its form is:

```
NIntegrate[f[x], {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, y}]
```

but for several reasons I need to evaluate the integral in the form (1).
I cannot use the 'Integrate' built-in function for the symbolic intgeral beacuse the function I have to integrate is very complicated and the time to solve it symbolically is huge.

Is there a way to bypass the error that appears in (1) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a second function with the inner integral and give the restriction that it is only evaluated if the argument is numeric. E.g.:

```
f[x_] = x;
f1[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, y}]
NIntegrate[f1[y], {y, 0, 1}]
(* 0.166667 *)
```

Comment: Thanks, I need a little more... Is there a way to define, for example, the variable 'L[1]' as a blank variable like 'f[L[1]_]:=L[1]^2'?

Comment: That will not work. MMA interprets this as L[1] times underscore.  However this is superfluous. In  "f[x_]", "x_" means  any expression and your "L[1]_" would mean the same thing.